# SQL - Check for different records in single table

Tags: sql

How would you write a statement to check for each item and y/n or 1/0 for sites if the record exists.

| Item | site |
| --- | --- |
| ItemA | SiteA |
| ItemA | SiteB |
| ItemA | SiteC |
| ItemB | SiteB |
| ItemC | SiteA |

Exptected Results

```
|Item | CheckA| CheckB |CheckC|
|:---- | :----| :----| :----| 
|ItemA |Y| Y| Y|
|ItemB |N| Y| N |
|ItemC |N | N| Y|
```

Thank you all,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select item,
       max(case when site = 'SiteA' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as CheckA,
       max(case when site = 'SiteB' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as CheckB,
       max(case when site = 'SiteC' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as CheckC
from t
group by item;
```